# React control modal from multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an MyError modal which I need to open from various nested components.

```
<App>
   <Header>
      <MyError open={boolean}>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <Component 1>
          <Inner1 opens myError>
       </Component1>
       <Component 2>
          <Inner2 opens MyError>
       </Component1>
   </Body>
</App>
```

The actual inner component that opens MyError may be nested several layers deep.
Whats the cleanest way these various inner components can open the modal (with a message)?
I thought of using `ref`, `useImperativeHandle`and/or `useReducer` in some way but I can't think of a clean implementation. I even thought of having a route to the component and then simply adding a fragment to the URL.

No Redux or other external reducers please.

Comment: Use redux to keep a state independent of components. Use that state to check if the modal should be open or closed.

Comment: Place your modal to the root of the component tree and toggle its visibility through context or redux.

Comment: You might want to check out [these codepens](https://codepen.io/collection/XRMdwg)

Comment: Some people seem to have ignored the **no Redux** statement,
Only React Hooks reducers permitted.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simple & clean solutions would be using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

First, create and export a `ModalContext`, wrap all of your children components inside `<ModalContext.Provider>`, keep the `isOpen` and `modalMessage` inside React states of your `<App />`.

Then pass their state setter function as `Context` values like this:

```
export const ModalContext = createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [modalMessage, setModalMessage] = useState("default message");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen}>
        {modalMessage}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>close</button>
      </Modal>
      <ModalContext.Provider value={{ setIsOpen, setModalMessage }}>
        <Comp1 />
        <Comp2 />
      </ModalContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then inside one of your child components that you want to open `<Modal />`, import the `ModalContext` that exported above, use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to get the setter functions and use it like this:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ModalContext } from "./App";

export function Comp1() {
  const modalContext = useContext(ModalContext);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        modalContext.setIsOpen(true);
        modalContext.setModalMessage("Component 1");
      }}
    >
      Open modal 1
    </button>
  );
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-euclid-suwgl?file=/src/App.js)

Here I'm using `react-modal` for simplicity, but with your own `<Modal />`, the idea should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your example, seriously considering something like this except may dispatch the actions